# Does a dependency count as a download in npm stats

Tags: node.js, statistics, npm

How is the download count behind the npm stats calculated? 
Does one download of Mongoose count as one download of MongoDB as well (because it has MongoDB as a dependency)?

Looking at the stats of [Mongoose](http://npm-stat.com/charts.html?package=mongoose&author=&from=&to=) and [MongoDB](http://npm-stat.com/charts.html?package=mongodb&author=&from=&to=), Mongoose has approximately half as many downloads as MongoDB. Does this mean that approximately 50% of the users download Mongoose and the others plain MongoDB, since every download of Mongoose might count as a download of MongoDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an explanation on same topic: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/92574016600/numeric-precision-matters-how-npm-download-counts-work.html

Comment: So in short, Does one download of Mongoose count as one download of MongoDB as well (because it has MongoDB as a dependency)? I couldn't figure out this from the article.

Comment: @Wajahath me too, read it 2-3 times and still couldn't figure out the answer from the article. I guess the sole purpose of the article is to tell that download counts in a package are never totally accurate.

Comment: links' broken, here's new: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/92574016600/numeric-precision-matters-how-npm-download-counts-work.html